# Persisting data to database. persist not working

Tags: database, symfony

I wrote a controller action that is supposed to add an element (meeting) to the database here it is:

```
public function newAction(Request $request){
    $meeting = new Meeting();
    $meetingUser = new MeetingUser();
    $project = new Project();
    $projectName = "SocialPro";//$request->get('projectName');
    echo($projectName);
    $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SocialProMeetingBundle:meetingUser')->findProjectUser($projectName);
    //$form = $this->createForm('SocialPro\MeetingBundle\Form\MeetingType', $meeting);
    //$form->handleRequest($request);
    //if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $userconn = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    echo($userconn->getId());
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        echo("message form");
        $role = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SocialProMeetingBundle:meetingUser')->findUserRole($userconn)[0]['role'];
        $date = $request->get('date');
        if ($role == "PROJECT_MASTER" || $role == "TEAM_MASTER") {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {
                $meetings = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SocialProMeetingBundle:meetingUser')->findMeetingUser($users[$i]['id'], $date);
            }
            if ($meetings == null || count($meetings) == 0) {
                $project = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SocialProProjectBundle:Project')->findBy(array("name" = >$projectName));
                $meeting->setDescription($request->get('description'));
                $meeting->setDate(new \DateTime($request->get('date')));
                $meeting->setTime($request->get('time'));
                $meeting->setProjectName($request->get('projectName'));
                $meeting->setProject($project[0]);


                $meetingUser->setMeetings($meeting);
                $meetingUser->setUsers($userconn);
                var_dump($meetingUser);
                $meeting->setMeetingUser(array($meetingUser));
                //$project->setMeetings($meeting->getId());
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $em->persist($meeting);
                $em->persist($meetingUser);
                $em->flush();
                // $meetingUser->setUsers($request->get(''));
                return $this->redirectToRoute('reunion_show', array('id' = > $meeting->getId()));
            }
            else {
                echo("Membre indisponible");
            }
        }
        else {
            echo("Must be MASTER to create meeting");
        }
    }
    return $this->render('SocialProMeetingBundle::ajoutMeeting.html.twig', array('users' = >$users));
    // $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //$em->persist($meeting);
    //$em->flush($meeting);

    // return $this->redirectToRoute('meeting_show', array('id' => $meeting->getId()));
    //}

    //return $this->render('SocialProMeetingBundle:ajouMeeting', array(
    //  'meeting' => $meeting,
    //'form' => $form->createView(),
    //));
}
```

When I submit the form it gives me a site not available page. I tested it line by line and everything is working perfectly. Turns out the problem is in the

```
$em->persist($meeting);
```

And I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Is it a 404 error or a 500 error? Did you look in your log files?

Comment: @el_wichtel This is the error I got in console: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: With console you mean the log file? So please post the complete log entry and check your databse connection.

Answer (score 0):

You must call flush immediately after calling persist like so:

```
$em->persist( $meeting );
$em->flush();

$em->persist( $meetingUser );
$em->flush();
```

Then it will persist both.

Comment: A new entity was found through the relationship 'SocialPro\MeetingBundle\Entity\Meeting#meetingUser' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: SocialPro\MeetingBundle\Entity\MeetingUser. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'SocialPro\MeetingBundle\Entity\MeetingUser#__toString()' to get a clue.

Comment: I see that there are a lot of problems with your code, and it's hard to make a simple recommendation. Have you already gone through the [Symfony Doctrine documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)? If not, i suggest you go through that first. Essentially, looking at your code, you probably need to create a `MeetingUser` object first and persist it, and then create the `Meeting` object and add the `MeetingUser` object and then persist. I don't know how you've created your entities, so I can't make good suggestions.